# Is Client Connected in Asp.net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a long streaming operation, that I would like to be able to cancel if the client is disconnected.

How can I know the state of the connection or if the client is disconnected?
The client is likely to be a web browser.

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendStream(string account, string container)
{
    var responseContent = new PushStreamContent(async (stream, content, context) =>
    {
        do
        {
            //get some data
            stream.Write(chunkData, 0, chunkLength);

        } while (IsClientStileConnected && moreWork);

    }, "application/octet-stream");

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = responseContent;

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `HttpResponse.IsClientConnected` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.isclientconnected(v=vs.110).aspx? You can get access to the HttpContext although it's not a very WebApi way of doing things.

Comment: I m going to try that thank you

Comment: hello I tried it doesn't work, it doesn't compile

Severity Code Description Project File Line
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HttpResponse.IsClientConnected'

Comment: you'll need to access it via `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected` watch out though as this isn't good practice and in some cases (async on difference thread) HttpContext.Current will be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PushStreamContent.ctor has an Action<Stream, HttpContent, TransportContext> delegate that gives you the ChannelBinding which has an IsClosed and IsInvalid property.

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse();

response.Content = new PushStreamContent(
    async (outputStream, httpContent, transportContext) => {
        foreach(var something in somethings) {
            .
            if(transportContext.GetChannelBinding().IsClosed)
                break;
        }
    }
);
```